# Apply css to images based on width (jquery)

Tags: jquery

(Pertaining to Tumblr's photosets)

Photosets automatically resize images to the post (div) width, and this means that if the post div is 540px, then the photoset will automatically resize itself to fit that. The issue with this is that it resizes the smaller image types (it ranges from 540px, to 268px, and then 177~178px in size, but we're focusing on 268px) without considering the margin, which should be 4px. This means that where the 268px images should be 268px, they resize to around 270px. I found a temporary fix by setting the width of post divs to 536px instead, but that resized the largest images to be slightly smaller than I want, and I have yet to figure out to fix this.

Is there a way to use a jquery code to apply a max-width of 268px to anything that is 268px and smaller in photosets, but leave anything larger alone? I've tried a couple codes floating around, but I can't seem to get Tumblr to respond to them, so I'll post one of them here to see if I made a mistake. I can apply/modify the margin separately without the usage of jquery, so I already have that handled, I just need the images themselves to be resized properly. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.posts img').each(function(){
        if($(this).width() > 268){
        $(this).css('max-width', '268px');}
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the `max-width` property/value showing up as an inline style attribute at all?

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded anywhere in your template file? Either in the head or before the close of your body?

Comment: Yeah, I do. I have other scripts loaded (they don't interfere with this one, since I've tried to take them out and nothing changes) so I already have everything loaded properly; the issue isn't that, I think.

Comment: Are you able to do any jQuery related methods aside from the one you've mentioned here?

Comment: So far, the other stuff I have loaded (which work) are css-styled tooltips and pxu-photoset; if you want I can post the codes for those, but like I said, removing those doesn't resolve the issue. (I think I read your question right, and if I didn't, I'm sorry.)

Comment: No problem. Are you writing your scripts in a separate `.js` file or is it directly on the template inside a `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: Separate .js files that I reference with the scripts. Also, since both scripts aren't ones I wrote directly, just edited for my own use, I didn't modify the .js files myself and only modified the contents in the scripts themselves.

Comment: I'm wondering if the js file is being referenced correctly because when I ran your code it seemed to work. Can you post the tag you're pulling the script from?

Comment: Sure:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/qudkd6d/Az6nkemqr/pxuphotoset.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/rzl30kg/eAxm7a751/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>`

Comment: The `query.min.js` file resides at the top of your scripts correct?

Comment: That made it work! However I found an error in my own jquery code (oops): It should be smaller than/equal to 268px, not larger than, but when I reversed the >, it stopped responding again. Does it not have a reverse function?

Comment: How about `if ($(this).width() <= 268)`?

Comment: I managed to get it to work!! Thank you so much, this is a problem I've been trying to fix for months. Thank you!!!

Comment: Happy to help! Would you mind marking my answer as correct.

Comment: I did, and again thank you!

Comment: No problem. Good luck on the rest of your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like you need to place your `query.min.js` above the rest of your scripts in order for jQuery to work properly:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/qudkd6d/Az6nkemqr/pxuphotoset.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/rzl30kg/eAxm7a751/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></s‌​cript>
```

And to find all images less than or equal to 268px try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.posts img').each(function(){
      if ($(this).width() <= 268) {
        $(this).css('max-width', '268px');
      }
    });
});
```